# Creating rolling window for time series data in SQL

Tags: sql-server, window

I have a question regarding adding rolling window column in SQL. Table A is a sample of 24 months time series data. I need to add column for difference between each month balances with pervious month and a month before pervious month. For example for Mar 2020 I need to have difference between Mar and Feb and also Mar and Jan for Deposit and Withdraw separately for each ID (Table B). I try to use 'window' function in sql  but I do not know how.

```
 **Table A**
 ID      | Date      |A      | B       |
+--------+-----------+-------+---------
| 1      | Jan 20    | $200  | $100    |
| 1      | Feb 20    | $500  | $250    |
| 1      | Mar 20    | $1000 | $550    | 
+--------+-----------+-------+---------+
```

I want results like this:

```
 **Table B**
 ID      | Date      |A      | B       | A(Mar-Feb)| A(Mar-Jan)| B(Mar-Feb)| B(Mar-Jan)|
+--------+-----------+-------+------------------------------------------------------
| 1      | Jan 20    | $200  | $100    |            |           |          |           |
| 1      | Feb 20    | $500  | $250    |            |           |          |           |
| 1      | Mar 20    | $1000 | $550    | $500       |$800       |$300      |$450       |
+--------+-----------+-------+---------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

I'd really appreciated if someone can help me.

Comment: *" I try to use "window" function in sql but I do not know how."* So what was your attempt and why didn't it work. We can't tell you  why your attempt didn't work if you don't show us said attempt(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: See edit at bottom for corrected answer based on more information from OP

I "think" this is what you're asking for and it may not perfectly be what you want, because it fills in the other rows as well...

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableA','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TableA; --SELECT * FROM #TableA
CREATE TABLE #TableA (
    ID     int  NOT NULL,
    [Date] date NOT NULL,
    A      int  NOT NULL,
    B      int  NOT NULL,
)

INSERT INTO #TableA (ID, Date, A, B)
VALUES (1, '2020-01-01',  200, 100)
    ,  (1, '2020-02-01',  500, 250)
    ,  (1, '2020-03-01', 1000, 550)

SELECT ta.ID
    , [Date] = FORMAT(ta.[Date],'MMM yy')
    , ta.A, ta.B
    , A_DiffPrev  = ta.A - LAG(ta.A)         OVER (ORDER BY ta.[Date])
    , A_DiffFirst = ta.A - FIRST_VALUE(ta.A) OVER (ORDER BY ta.[Date])
    , B_DiffPrev  = ta.B - LAG(ta.B)         OVER (ORDER BY ta.[Date])
    , B_DiffFirst = ta.B - FIRST_VALUE(ta.B) OVER (ORDER BY ta.[Date])
FROM #TableA ta
```

Returns:

```plaintext
| ID | Date   | A    | B   | A_DiffPrev | A_DiffFirst | B_DiffPrev | B_DiffFirst | 
|----|--------|------|-----|------------|-------------|------------|-------------| 
| 1  | Jan 20 | 200  | 100 | NULL       | 0           | NULL       | 0           | 
| 1  | Feb 20 | 500  | 250 | 300        | 300         | 150        | 150         | 
| 1  | Mar 20 | 1000 | 550 | 500        | 800         | 300        | 450         |
```

---

### Explanation

- `LAG(ta.A) OVER (ORDER BY ta.[Date])` - This will give you the previous value as sorted by the provided `ORDER BY`. So in this case, it's saying, give me the value that occurs prior to the current row, if you sort by `[Date]` Ascending
- `FIRST_VALUE(ta.A) OVER (ORDER BY ta.[Date])` - Similar idea to `LAG()` except it's saying to get the very first item, rather than the previous item.

---

### Edit

In the comments you mentioned that `FIRST_VALUE()` will not work for you because you don't want to compare with the first month, you want to compare with the previous month and two months back.

In that case, you can use this solution:

```sql
SELECT ta.ID
    , [Date] = FORMAT(ta.[Date],'MMM yy')
    , ta.A, ta.B
    , A_DiffPrev1 = ta.A - LAG(ta.A,1) OVER (ORDER BY ta.[Date])
    , A_DiffPrev2 = ta.A - LAG(ta.A,2) OVER (ORDER BY ta.[Date])
    , B_DiffPrev1 = ta.B - LAG(ta.B,1) OVER (ORDER BY ta.[Date])
    , B_DiffPrev2 = ta.B - LAG(ta.B,2) OVER (ORDER BY ta.[Date])
FROM #TableA ta
```

Explanation:

In this change, I'm using `LAG()` for everything. But instead, I'm telling `LAG()` how many rows I want it to look back.

So to get the previous month, I say `LAG(A, 1)` which means to grab the previous row, which is the default, I'm only providing it here to make it more explicitly clear what is happening.

Then I say `LAG(A, 2)` which means to go back two rows and grab that value.

NOTE: This is all assuming you do not have gaps in your data.

Comment: Thanks @Chadbaldwin, I have 2 years monthly data and looking for differences with pervious month and 2 month ago, so in this case 'FIRST_VALUE(ta.A) OVER (ORDER BY ta.[Date])' cannot help.

Comment: Ah okay. I recommend updating your question to make that clear.

Comment: @Mike refresh the page and see the edit at the bottom of my answer. I've added an adjusted answer that should get what you want.